# Array 1D right rotation in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I wish to rotate the elements of an array k times to the right(where k is an int), the array is of size n(int n), You can see my code for this below, I'm unsure of how to proceed when array[n+k] hits a[n-1]

I'm trying to wrap the a[n-1] around to be a[0] and then continue the rotation as needed. I'm aware others have solved this in different ways but I'm asking utilizing my code and adjusting it how it can work.

My code:

```
package com.company;
//Make an array that rotates n members k times
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RightRotationArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //I want an array with a size n
        int n;
        int k;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a size for the array: ");
        n= input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter in a shift to the array: ");
        k= input.nextInt();
        //Declare the array
        int[] array1= new int[n];
        //now input elements into the array
        for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter in a value: ");
            array1[i]= input.nextInt();
            //want to make the array right rotate so everyone is shifted right
            for(int a= 0; a<n-1; a++){
                array1[a]= array1[a+k];//shifting step
                //need an if to catch the above size declaration
                if(array1[a+k]== array1[n-1]){
                    array1[n-1] = array1[0];

                }
            }
        }
        //print out the array to verify
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    }

}
```

Comment: You have the rotiating code in the loop that should fill the array. Is that intended? I'd expect the rotation taking place after the filling process.

Comment: simplify your problem before you move to adding integers by input from the user, it will save you a vast amount of time when testing your shift logic

Comment: I would suggest you to NEVER mix user inputs with your logic/algorithms. Get your data first, THEN you go on with your calculations. This is a general advice always usable: always separate logic, data and interface in three distinct blocks

Comment: @Lothar yep that was intended, but I took it out briefly and it didn't make much of a difference on my output.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I agree, thanks!

Comment: @Oneiros you're right!, that provides better readability too, thanks!

Comment: Modulo does the trick, see my answer (the alternative solution)

Comment: @Lothar ah I see thank you so much, this makes more sense to me now!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ShiftArray {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        int steps = 5;
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        rotateArray(array, steps);
        Arrays.stream(array)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        // alternate approach doing the shifring while filling:

        array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            int index = (i + steps) % newArray.length;
            newArray[index] = array[i];
        }

        System.out.println("================");

        Arrays.stream(newArray)
        .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    public static void rotateArray(int[] array, int steps) {
        int[] tempArray = new int[steps];
        System.arraycopy(array, array.length - steps, tempArray, 0, steps);
        for (int i = array.length - steps - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array[i + steps] = array[i];
        }
        System.arraycopy(tempArray, 0, array, 0, steps);
    }

}
```

Depending on the size of the array and the value of `steps` the first solution might lead to memory problems.

Comment: thanks! So is the basic premise to make a new copy of the array?

Comment: @JoshSteier I edited my answer with a second solution. What's "best" depends on the concrete situaion, there is no single solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple bit of math to rotate the array, just note that you should always check what the result of adding your shift to your index before trying to access it. In your example you assume you can access array1[a+k] which is not always the case. You'll also need to account for shift values greater than the length of the array created, therefore the % is used to ensure valid indices.

```
        int[] array1 = {1,6,8,4,9,2,0,-1};
        int[] arrayShifted = new int[array1.length];
        int shift = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            if(i + shift < array1.length)
                arrayShifted[i+shift] = array1[i];
            else
                arrayShifted[Math.abs(array1.length - (i + shift))%array1.length] = array1[i];
        }
```

Output

```
Shift = 0 //sanity check
1 6 8 4 9 2 0 -1

Shift = 2
0 -1 1 6 8 4 9 2

Shift = 5
4 9 2 0 -1 1 6 8

Shift = 16 //rotated length*2 so values should remain in their same location
1 6 8 4 9 2 0 -1

Shift = 17
-1 1 6 8 4 9 2 0
```